# create NSArray with NSDictionary objects from macro

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray, nsdictionary

What I am trying to accomplish, I've one macro defined,

```
#define NAME_List @"a,aaa,aac,aacaaba,abbbb"
```

I'm converting this to `NSArray` using `componentsSeperatedByString:` its fine giving me array of `NSString` objects, instead I want `NSDictionary` objects, something like,

> [0] -> "Name" = "a"
>
> [1] -> "Name" = "aaa"
>
> [2] -> "Name" = "aac""

& not like,

> [0] - > a
>   [1] - > aaa
>   [2] - > aac

I tried this (but I don't have any idea for `NSKeyedArchiver` or `NSPropertyListFormat` or 
`NSPropertyListSerialization` classes)

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arrayNames];
NSError *error = nil; 
NSPropertyListFormat plistFormat; 
NSDictionary *temp = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&plistFormat error:&error];
```

**Update**

I can iterate through array and create dictionary object and add it to array to do this, but I don't want to do it like this!

**Is there any functions available which can do this?**

Comment: Have you tried '[NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeys:someArray andValues:someOtherArray]'? You would need to specify keys for your dictionary anyway, afaik...

Comment: are you sure you want without loop/iteration/recursion?

Comment: Yes, if its possible! I'm looking for some good alternatives which is faster then looping it! I'm only showing few string in question, in real there are 72k+ strings

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *resultArr = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *arr = [NAME_LIST componentsSeperatedByString:@","];
for(NSString *str in arr) {
    NSDictionary *nameDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:str forKey:@"Name"];
    [resultArr addObject:nameDictionary];
}
NSLog(@"%@", resultArr);
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, I am known with this method! :) Please check my updated question!